# CSS Drag Up But not cover text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a div to be within a div of height 100%. However it should get pushed out when the text reaches the end, and not cover the rest.

```
    .window{
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
overflow:auto;}

   a.spacer{
padding-top: 50px;
margin-top:-50px;
display: block;
height:50px;
background-image:url('uparrow.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center;}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code here in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a padding-top: 50px; will keep your arrow inside the div but also give you some breathing room for elements above.